# How to get Unix-style date from JS/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time

I am looking for a date with this format:

```
Fri Jul 12 13:41:12 PDT 2019
```

or ideally in UTC:

```
Fri Jul 12 10:41:12 UTC 2019
```

if I run this in JS: `console.log(new Date())` I get something like this:

```
2019-07-12T20:43:04.432Z
```

I just find the unix date stamp more palatable for humans.

Comment: Something like this? `new Date().toUTCString()`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to follow that exact format, something like this could work:

```js
var dateSplit = new Date().toUTCString().replace("GMT", "UTC").replace(",", "").split(" ");

console.log(`${dateSplit[0]} ${dateSplit[2]} ${dateSplit[1]} ${dateSplit[4]} ${dateSplit[5]} ${dateSplit[3]}`);
```

Note: GMT can be replaced by UTC because they are essentially the same in practice

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get something close to that would be using the toUTCString Date method. That out puts in this format: "Fri, 12 Jul 2019 20:49:50 GMT".

Another option would be using the various getters in the Date class like getFullYear to create your own format. I haven't personally done that so I can't speak on the exact way to do it. CSS-Tricks does have [this article](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/) that may be of help.

Comment: can you show the exact code you used

Comment: That isn't the format produced by [*toUTCString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring), the month name comes before the day number. But yes, it's close. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) even for formatting for different locales, or you can look for more lightweight alternatives on npm.

Comment: Something like `date-fns` would be a lot more lightweight than `moment`. `moment`'s API is *really* heavy.

Comment: Saying "*use library X*" isn't an answer, it might be a useful comment (but likely not in this case).